# wget with proxy not bypassing ip block?

Tags: http, proxy, ip, httprequest, wget

This is about a server A which I use to browse the website pixiv.net.

One day, all my http requests (pings or wget) from this server stopped working (they keep timing out). I concluded it was most likely an IP block from pixiv, blocking the IP of server A.

I luckily have access to another server B which I could use for testing, this one is able to issue requests to pixiv just fine (but I cant use it permanently it's not mine).

To bypass what I thought was an IP block, I tried to issue the HTTP requests through proxies. I've tried a few different ones, courtesy of https://gimmeproxy.com/, but the requests still time out. However, they still work fine from server B even with proxy, which leads me to believe there is nothing wrong with the proxy.

I've concluded that one of the following is true:

- I'm misusing wget with proxy and I'm actually not doing anything at all. I'm doing

wget pixiv.net -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=ip:port

- Proxies don't help solving my IP block issue.
- The original issue is not an IP block. In that case I have no idea what it could be

Comment: Its possible that you are just timing out (even with the proxy) because the site seems really slow. Try curl with a `-v` option. That way, you can see is it connecting to the server or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The line where the timeout happens is "Connexion towards pixiv.net", so I think the connexion is not happening. The failure is really consistent through my many attempts, and only on that server A, so I doubt it's only because of the slowness of the website =/